# Git filter-repo - failed on add files to root commit

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

Trying to add file to the root of the branch fails with following error:

```
git filter-repo --force --commit-callback "if not commit.parents: commit.file_changes.append(FileChange(b'M', 'C:\MDC\MDC.7z', $(git hash-object -w 'C:\MDC\MDC.7z'), 100644))"

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core\git-filter-repo", line 3839, in <module>
    filter = RepoFilter(args)
  File "C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core\git-filter-repo", line 2661, in __init__
    self._handle_arg_callbacks()
  File "C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core\git-filter-repo", line 2763, in _handle_arg_callbacks
    handle('commit')
  File "C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core\git-filter-repo", line 2756, in handle
    setattr(self, callback_field, make_callback(type, code_string))
  File "C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core\git-filter-repo", line 2741, in make_callback
    exec('def callback({}, _do_not_use_this_var = None):\n'.format(argname)+
  File "<string>", line 2
    if not commit.parents: commit.file_changes.append(FileChange(b'M', 'C:\MDC\MDC.7z', 3d5fb68077a1d627a7ec3b18f335713c4262fbf0, 100644))
                                                                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Windows 10
Git Version 2.24

https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo

Comment: https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/issues/21#issuecomment-558218563

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Python point of view `3d5fb68077a1d627a7ec3b18f335713c4262fbf0` must be a string (`'3d5fb68077a1d627a7ec3b18f335713c4262fbf0'`), so put quotes around it:

```
--commit-callback "if not commit.parents: commit.file_changes.append(FileChange(b'M', 'C:\MDC\MDC.7z', '$(git hash-object -w 'C:\MDC\MDC.7z')', 100644))"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
git filter-repo --force --commit-callback "if not commit.parents: commit.file_changes.append(FileChange(b'M', b'MDC.7z', bytes('$(git hash-object -w 'C:\MDC\MDC.7z')',encoding='utf-8'), b'100644'))"
```

1. The 2th param of FileChange should like run `git rev-list --objects --all` 's path.
2. Each param of FileChange must type of bytes, so:

- `100644` -> `b'100644'`
- `$(git hash-object -w 'C:\MDC\MDC.7z')` -> `bytes('$(git hash-object -w 'C:\MDC\MDC.7z')',encoding='utf-8')`

Example:

```sh
$ git filter-repo --force --commit-callback "if not commit.parents: commit.file_changes.append(FileChange(b'M', b'1.txt', bytes('$(git hash-object -w 'D:\tmp\git\git1\1.txt')',encoding='utf-8'), b'100644'))"
Parsed 3 commitsHEAD is now at 067c5a4 add 5.txt
Enumerating objects: 10, done.
Counting objects: 100% (10/10), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.
Writing objects: 100% (10/10), done.
Total 10 (delta 2), reused 3 (delta 0)

New history written in 0.68 seconds; now repacking/cleaning...
Repacking your repo and cleaning out old unneeded objects
Completely finished after 2.18 seconds.
```

Comment: git hash-object seems to be a command-line git command and not a python code. How is it working? Actually I wanted to programmatically determine the path of the file passed to git hash-object command. But I am not able to do so.